# Edit 2nd legend title in ggraph geom_edge_fan

Tags: r, legend, ggraph

Aside from the chart being cluttered...Just trying to capitalize the legend title for the geom_edge_fan legend title.

```
    ggraph(network_ee, layout="nicely") +
  geom_edge_fan(aes(width=frequency, label=frequency), color="gray65", arrow=arrow(length=unit(2,"mm"), type="closed"), end_cap=circle(3,"mm"), angle_calc = "across",label_color = "gray60", label_dodge = unit(5, "mm")) +  
  labs(title="Emails", subtitle="Frequency of Internal Communication")+
  scale_edge_width(range=c(0.4, 1.75)) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color=factor(department)), size=5, alpha=.8) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "yellow", "orange", "darkgreen", "blue", "purple")) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label=employee), repel=TRUE, vjust=0.5) + 
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Department"))+
  ##guides(width=guide_legend(title="Frequency"))+
  ##guides(size=guide_legend(title="Frequency"))+
  ##guides(label=guide_legend(title="Frequency"))+
  ##guides(shape=guide_legend(title="Frequency"))+
  ##guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Frequency"))+
  theme_graph()
```

want frequency to be Frequency

in R code, I've commented out failed attempts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
scale_edge_width(range=c(0.4, 1.75), name="Frequency") +
```

modified line "scale_edge_width(range=c(0.4, 1.75))+" with the above